# Chrome tab memory release retaining cookies

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I'm scrolling down a page which loads data with JavaScript (Unlimited Scroll). After some time, chrome uses lot of RAM. If I refresh the page, I'll have to again scroll from the first result again.
I saw this in chrome memory tab which shows almost 1.7 GB of heap size. How can I release this memory?
[Memory Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJx79.png)

Or is there any way to restore the cookies, session so that after closing the browser I can retain my scroll location.

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+DEL Try to delete  "images a files stored in cache" in the last hour. Don't know if the use of RAM will drop down and I don't know if this will mess with your scroll location.

Comment: Deleting images logged me out of the website.

Comment: I deleted only images and files (no cookies) from a Pinterest page and I haven't been logged out. But trying this method twice I've noticed that browser have not cleared so many MByte as stated at first time. Sorry, I don't know what to suggest further